# Minimal example of TAILQ usage out of <sys/queue.h> library

Tags: c, linux, gcc, queue

Can some one provide minimal example of TAILQ usage out of linux system library with explanation in c which can be compiled using gcc in Linux?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `TAILQ_ENTRY` macro is used to establish the pointers used to insert items into the list. You place it into your structure that you want to list up.

```
struct foo {
    TAILQ_ENTRY(foo) tailq;
    int datum;
    /* ... */
};
```

The `TAILQ_HEAD` is used to define a structure that will act as the container for your link list elements. You provide it with a structure name, and the name of the type that it will contain.

```
TAILQ_HEAD(fooq, foo);
```

Use `TAILQ_INIT` to initialize an instance of your list container.

```
struct fooq q;
TAILQ_INIT(&q);
```

Use the `TAILQ_INSERT_*` macros to add elements.

```
struct foo data[3] = { foo(3), foo(7), foo(1) };
TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(&q, &data[0], tailq);
TAILQ_INSERT_AFTER(&q, &data[0], &data[1], tailq);
TAILQ_INSERT_TAIL(&q, &data[2], tailq);
```

You can use `TAILQ_FOREACH` and `TAILQ_FOREACH_REVERSE` to traverse the list.

```
struct foo *p;
TAILQ_FOREACH(p, &q, tailq) {
    printf(" %d", p->datum);
}
puts("");
```

If you want to iterate over the list while removing all its elements, it is probably easier to use a while loop and use the `TAILQ_EMPTY` and `TAILQ_FIRST` macros.

```
while (!TAILQ_EMPTY(&q)) {
    p = TAILQ_FIRST(&q);
    TAILQ_REMOVE(&q, p, tailq);
    /* ... */
}
```

The above code was mostly taken verbatim from an example I wrote and tested on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/D67BHW).

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVJda4MwFH3Pr7hzrMRhN7s@7MGtIFtKhbXdUimMUYqoXQVr/YhbR/G3u0QtjaXsaRGjuTn3nMu51@1@um5ZXgaRG@aeDw8Z84LtzXqApNBPdpvkfu6LMMpYmrsMVtst7BHwZZvWy9uSTGz6jnlUBeYEYWJUd0HEwHNYvjFQYbRyxYvF9ZcTqg2TdL2DR9jzR9dAh0ITKChqztRneRrBjlMiVIuPiPkstBNNJKtcSTBvnCACrKJT8gSa6iQ9XqTz0V9UqvyM@2pFhe@bb089yEtJ1zFXOlpgTSwbdxLVaMVmhNp1gR1eXqcS0hda7dI5rDm0CT0B13@9v9LEQcq6k7ASeDilxHwa4ZjjkgOisV@sOOXOrbACV56iQdwdVN1r9Ipqj3OWYUU5y7ukZE7ojBz46578g8r3Ogh9wBfNsI1f7XdhdYuUN68pxqIzqRPHKikZT@ekciluW1kgebZ0Pltl@Qs "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: A nice but confusing example.  Calling everything 'foo*' including 'struct foo ... and function foo() should be part of a code obfuscation contest.

Comment: @stevea It is fairly common to indicate different data structures are related by name. In this case, a `fooq` is a queue container for `foo` structures.

Comment: Related, yet different means you need a distinguishing name.  .  fooq as a pointer of 'struct foo' elements might get a pass,, but the peculiar and unnecessary partial initializer function 'foo' is over the top.

Comment: @stevea As you noted, the function name matches the name of the structure it is initializing.

Comment: Which, in C is overloading the term 'foo'.   bar, bletch qux exist for a reason.

Comment: @stevea I am just indicating the names coinciding is a feature. Search replace with a suitably different name makes the code just as usable to the same effect. I understand it is not to everyone's liking.

Comment: C doesn't have constructors, so overloading namespace with a function 'foo' and a struct 'foo' simply makes the C code less-readable.  new_foo() or mk_foo() would be more readable, *if* the trivial function wasn't extraneous & excessive for the example.

Comment: @stevea I appreciate your continued input. I hope we both can agree that not everyone will agree on coding styles and what constitutes readable code.

Answer (score 1):

Tho' jxh code/link above is algorithmically a nice example for TAILQ. I believe this a a more readable and didactic transliteration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/queue.h>

// our list element, with embedded links
struct elem {
    TAILQ_ENTRY(elem) _links;
    int datum;
    // ... other stuff goes here
};

// declare struct for a head of list of elem's
TAILQ_HEAD(list_of_elem, elem);

int main ()
{
    struct list_of_elem mylist;
    struct elem myelems[] = { {.datum = 3}, {.datum = 7}, {.datum = 1} };
    struct elem *pelem;

    TAILQ_INIT(&mylist);
    TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(&mylist, &myelems[0], _links);
    TAILQ_INSERT_AFTER(&mylist, &myelems[0], &myelems[1], _links);
    TAILQ_INSERT_TAIL(&mylist, &myelems[2], _links);

    TAILQ_FOREACH(pelem, &mylist, _links) {
        printf(" %d", pelem->datum);
    }
    puts("");

    TAILQ_FOREACH_REVERSE(pelem, &mylist, list_of_elem, _links) {
        printf(" %d", pelem->datum);
    }
    puts("");

    while (!TAILQ_EMPTY(&mylist)) {
        pelem = TAILQ_FIRST(&mylist);
        TAILQ_REMOVE(&mylist, pelem, _links);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: These examples using BSD 'queue macros that are included within structs can be efficient,but external functions to refer to arbitrary elements are often preferable.

Comment: I don't really agree this is more readable and didactic, but I support your desire to express your point of view. Upvoted.