# sys/queue.h error: request for member in something not a structure or union (TAILQ)

Tags: c, queue

I'm building a small file utility that relies on queues and I've been getting the error on compile:

```
error: request for member "entries" in something not a structure or union
```

I stripped it down to just the queue handling lines, and I'm getting the same error, here's the source for the header:

```
#ifndef _tailq_test_h
#define _tailq_test_h

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/queue.h>

struct tail_q {
    TAILQ_ENTRY(tail_q) entries;
    int item;
};

TAILQ_HEAD(tail_queue, tail_q);

static struct tail_queue queue;

int main();

#endif
```

And for the program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/queue.h>
#include "tailq-test.h"

static struct tail_queue queue;

int main()
{
    struct tail_q *q_ptr;
    int data = 1;

    TAILQ_INIT(&queue);

    TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(&queue, &data, entries);

    return 0;
}
```

The traceback refers to the line `TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(&queue, &data, entries);`, it has the same effect if `TAILQ_INSERT_TAIL` is used instead.

I'm not sure why it's not compiling. I checked the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315213/minimal-example-of-tailq-usage-out-of-sys-queue-h-library) and the provided example compiled just fine. I'm having trouble spotting the difference/what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's the question/answer I referenced in my question above. The example compiles, but my code doesn't, and I'm having trouble telling where the difference is.

Comment: I think you should look more closely, there are some differences. I didn't notice the link in your question originally - sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't too familiar with TAILQ, so I took a look at the source code that you can find here : http://www.gnu.org/software/mifluz/doc/doxydoc/queue_8h-source.html

Here is the source code for `TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD` :

```
#define TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(head, elm, field) do {                        
         if (((elm)->field.tqe_next = (head)->tqh_first) != NULL)        
                 (head)->tqh_first->field.tqe_prev =                     
                     &(elm)->field.tqe_next;
```

As you can see, the second parameter `elm` needs to be a struct containing the third parameter as a member (`field`).

In your situation, your second parameter is an `int *`, which does not have an `entries` member as pointed out by your error message.

From my understanding, you must pass a `tail_q` struct as your second parameter for your code to compile.

**EDIT :**
For example, the following code compiles :

```
int main()
{
    struct tail_q q;
    int data = 1;
    q.item = data; // Include your data in your struct.

    TAILQ_INIT(&queue);

    TAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(&queue, &q, entries); // Notice that I am passing a tail_q pointer here.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I got so preoccupied with "entries" I didn't notice my mistake was in the second argument.